# Rails devise cache refreshed at every request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Rails 6, Devise and Redis for caching.
If I run

> redis-cli monitor

I see that Rails try to fetch a key and it refresh the cache. Even if I just reload the same page or I change webpage during the same user-logged session. Maybe is it because of utm and referrer field on the user model?
utm/referrer are filled at user signup and they don't will never change.

This is an issue because I perform a "get"/"set" operation when I just need a "get".

> 1604411976.019840 [0 [::1]:50683] "get" "_session_id:2::252360dc050fb8d65e84a43a7a55da72ce1428fbdde4d9cda696296e3bdb130d"
>
> 1604411978.440996 [0 [::1]:50683] "set" "_session_id:2::252360dc050fb8d65e84a43a7a55da72ce1428fbdde4d9cda696296e3bdb130d"
> "\x04\bo: ActiveSupport::Cache::Entry\t:\x0b@value{\nI"\x0fsession_id\x06:\x06ETI"%45f803f32b1a89b8d6b0fc38ff90b00c\x06;\aTI"\x19warden.user.user.key\x06;\aT[\a[\x06i\x06I""$2a$11$6p01wAYCqmAGsjxzT40z8O\x06;\aTI"\butm\x06;\aT{\n:\x0bsource0:\rcampaign0:\x0bmedium0:\x0ccontent0:\tterm0I"\x10_csrf_token\x06;\aTI"1SzDbADoyFrsa/DwWutlecf+7RiSURygsxiU5+XL/o5c=\x06;\aTI"\rreferrer\x06;\aT"Ehttp://localhost:3000/en/profiles/34/items/35940:\r@version0:\x10@created_atf\x161604411978.440767:\x10@expires_in0

**config/devise**

```
config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable,  and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :trackable
```

**Schema.yml**

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string "email", default: "", null: false
        t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
        t.string "reset_password_token"
        t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
        t.datetime "remember_created_at"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
        t.string "locale"
        t.integer "sign_in_count"
        t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
        t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
        t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
        t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
        t.string "stripe_id"
        t.string "paypal"
        t.decimal "referral_commission"
        t.date "trial_end_date"
        t.string "coupon_code"
        t.json "utm"
        t.string "referrer"
        t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
        t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
      end
```

**config/application.rb**

```
config.middleware.insert_after ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Deflater
config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies # Required for all session management
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, config.session_options
```

The problem is not caused by the controller. There is no code.
app/controller/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # It happens even when I remove everything from here and page controller
end

class PagesController < ApplicationController
   def test
     render json: "ok"
   end
end
```

Comment: I'm surprised that nobody has answered here so far: From my perspective, it's almost impossible to help you with this problem unless you also share at least the bit of code (probably in the controller, since this is where you handle the session, right?) where you're interacting with the cache store.

Comment: I created a clean controller and remove any code from Application Controller and it still happens. Where else could I look at?

Comment: is this not more of a "feature" of redis, rather than with devise/cookies?

Comment: I think it’s caused by Devise because it only happens with the user object at each page load. Maybe because the current_user object is unequal at each request and it’s serialize differently each time. So redis cannot find the previous key and it creates a new key. But I don’t know why it’s always different and where look at

Answer (score 0):

Seems like rails uses it's own field for expiration instead of the native setx for redis.
If you notice, the last field from the active record cache is expires_in0

You have 3 pieces at play here. redis, devise and rails, gotta find which one has bad configs.
Try:

- passing a number in seconds for the expires_in facade you are using to cache
- checking the session.rb and cache.rb for default expiration times
- try to cache something else to see if it works

Comment: 1) This is done by devise and don't know where. 
2) Where can I find session.rb/cache.rb ? I haven't such files..  3) Caching something else it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

These writes are result of changes to `session` (data is `Marshal.dump`ed).

Some bytes look to be broken in example, but it looks like you have `referrer` written to session (`http://localhost:3000/en/profiles/34/items/35940` in example), which obviously change upon navigation and thus can result in writes.

Strange thing is that you have `session_store = :cookie_store`, but sessions are usually written to redis when `cache_store` is enabled